# Filtering a list with select knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am having problems with KnockoutJs. I have a select menu and an list which are both populated by the same locationsArray.Now i want to filter the list with the select menu that only the selected Location(in this case) stays in the list.
Is it possible to just hide the other list Items?

Thanks in advance

```
 <select data-bind="options: locations,value:selectedOption, optionsText: 'title'"></select> 

     <li data-bind="foreach: { data: locations, as: 'locations' }">
       <a data-bind=text:locations.title"> </a>
     </li>

var viewModel = {locations: ko.observableArray(locationsArray)};ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
var locationsArray =[{title:"Cinema",location:"NY"},{title:"Restaurant",location:"Miami"}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just introduce the following `getCurrentLocations()` method in your view-model:

```
var locationsArray =[{title:"Cinema",location:"NY"},{title:"Restaurant",location:"Miami"}];

var viewModel = {
    locations: ko.observableArray(locationsArray),
    selectedOption: ko.observable(''),
    getCurrentLocations: function() {
        var selectedVal = this.selectedOption();

        if (!selectedVal)
            return this.locations;

        return this.locations().filter(function(f) {
            return f.location == selectedVal.location;
        });
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And in your HTML:

```
<li data-bind="foreach: { data: getCurrentLocations(), as: 'locations' }">
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/haim770/3g7dxwh8/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I introduced the method but i'm getting error:
"knockout.js:72 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return { data:getCurrentLocations(),as:'locations'} }"(…)"

Comment: What about `{ data: $root.getCurrentLocations(), as: 'locations' }`? Did you actually add the method to your model?

Comment: Not working either.Yes I copied your code:)
"Message: this.locations.filter is not a function"

Comment: Try to replace each `this` with `viewModel` in `getCurrentLocations()`

Comment: Try to create a Fiddle to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Do you have an idea how to hide the remaining instead of filtering?

Comment: Created a fiddle with your code but still getting same error:
https://jsfiddle.net/Maru86/4pd5spbp/

Comment: @user2355793, I have updated the answer with code and working Fiddle

Comment: Dude your awesome!! Thank you so much.Works!One more question if you dont mind. How can I start the list with all locations available?

Comment: You want `getCurrentLocations()` to return all locations in case nothing is selected yet?

Comment: That would be great:)

Comment: See modified answer and Fiddle